# Image construction from two image of same object scanned at two resolution for micro and macro information

Tags: image-processing, image-stitching

I have SEM Image scanned at two magnifications, similar to this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7frwA.jpg). I want to merge these into a single image so that I can have information on pores at small scales and large scale.
I want to know how to create a single image from those 2D slices using python or Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use MATLAB [estimateGeometricTransform](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html) example:

```matlab
% Read the images.
I1 = rgb2gray(imread('macro.png'));
I2 = rgb2gray(imread('micro.png'));

% Reuse MATLAB example.
original = I1;
distorted = I2;

% Detect and extract features from the original and the transformed images.
% (Use more octaves and scales and lower threshold for improving robustness).
ptsOriginal  = detectSURFFeatures(original, 'NumOctaves', 5, 'NumScaleLevels', 5, 'MetricThreshold', 10);
ptsDistorted = detectSURFFeatures(distorted, 'NumOctaves', 5, 'NumScaleLevels', 5, 'MetricThreshold', 10);
[featuresOriginal,validPtsOriginal] = extractFeatures(original,ptsOriginal);
[featuresDistorted,validPtsDistorted] = extractFeatures(distorted,ptsDistorted);

% Match and display features between the images.
index_pairs = matchFeatures(featuresOriginal,featuresDistorted);
matchedPtsOriginal  = validPtsOriginal(index_pairs(:,1));
matchedPtsDistorted = validPtsDistorted(index_pairs(:,2));
figure
showMatchedFeatures(original,distorted,matchedPtsOriginal,matchedPtsDistorted)
title('Matched SURF Points With Outliers');

% Exclude the outliers, estimate the transformation matrix, and display the results.
[tform,inlierPtsDistorted,inlierPtsOriginal] = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPtsDistorted,matchedPtsOriginal, 'similarity');
figure
showMatchedFeatures(original,distorted, inlierPtsOriginal,inlierPtsDistorted);
title('Matched inlier points');   

%Recover the original image from the distorted image.
outputView = imref2d(size(original));
Ir = imwarp(distorted,tform,'OutputView',outputView);
figure; imshow(Ir); 
title('Recovered image');

% Visualize it somehow...
imshowpair(original, Ir)
```

---

Result:
[image]

Note:
I removed the text from the images manually.

Comment: Hi Rotem, Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it. Just a small request, I would like to have a single image as output without any border or highlights. Thanks again.

Comment: The focus of my answer is about (geometric) matching the two images. Visualizing the pair has too many options. Please edit your question, show what you have tried, and what is your goal, and I might find a solution.